# How to load class with options, e.g. headsepline

Tags: koma-script, document-classes, documentclass-writing

I'm trying to write my own class file for subsequent documents based on my template.

What I did is simply copy everthing from `\documentclass` to (but not including) `\begin{document}` and paste it into a new file called `myclass.cls`. Then I went on and replaced every `\usepackage` with `\RequirePackage` and `\documentclass` with `\LoadClass`. The document actually compiles but I'm missing lines in my header and footer.

This is my MWE which doesn't display any lines:

myclass.cls

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2016/02/21 My Class]

\LoadClass[
  a4paper, 
  headsepline, 
  footsepline, 
  numbers=noenddot, 
  captions=tableheading, 
  listof=totoc, 
  bibliography=totoc, 
  fontsize=10.5pt,
  toc=flat
]{scrartcl}

\RequirePackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
```

mydoc.tex

```
\documentclass{myclass}

\begin{document}
    \clearscrheadfoot
    \pagestyle{scrheadings}
    \ihead{header}

    Text
\end{document}
```

Without the separated class and everything in one file it works:

```
\documentclass[
  a4paper, 
  headsepline, 
  footsepline, 
  numbers=noenddot, 
  captions=tableheading, 
  listof=totoc, 
  bibliography=totoc, 
  fontsize=10.5pt,
  toc=flat
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\begin{document}
    \clearscrheadfoot
    \pagestyle{scrheadings}
    \ihead{header}

    Text
\end{document}
```

What am I missing? I think somehow the `headsepline` options isn't loaded with `\LoadClass`

Comment: [KOMA classes and \LoadClass](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27149) and [Converting preamble into a new class changes margins](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/257900) and [Unused global option in KOMAscript wrapper class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/242251)

Comment: Writing a proper (wrapper-)class is not that easy. Converting some template is even more complicated and the result often bad (imho).

Comment: I get the header and also the footer if I add `\ifoot{footer}`

Comment: @egreg header and footer are there but not the thin line between text body and header/footer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With class option `headsepline` there will be a line below of the header when page style `headings` is used. With class option `footsepline` the line above the footer is printed with both page style `headings` and page style `plain`. Note that these class options set also the `typearea` options `headinclude` and `footinclude`.

But you are loading package `scrlayer-scrpage` and this package has its own options `headsepline` and `footsepline`. They also have a different syntax: Using them you can also set a width and a length to the lines. But without any values they simple activate the lines with .4pt width and the same length as header/footer.

While `\documentclass` passes the options to the packages options set with `\LoadClass` are not seen by the packages. So `scrlayer-scrpage` does not know that there should be lines below header and above footer. So you have to set the options explicitly for `scrlayer-scrpage`.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{myclass.cls}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2016/02/21 My Class]
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\LoadClass[
  numbers=noenddot,
  captions=tableheading,
  listof=totoc,
  bibliography=totoc,
  fontsize=10.5pt,
  toc=flat,
  DIV=calc
]{scrartcl}

\KOMAoptions{
  headinclude,
  footinclude
}
\recalctypearea

\RequirePackage[headsepline,footsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{myclass}
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{Header Text}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

or

```
\begin{filecontents*}{myclass.cls}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2016/02/21 My Class]
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\LoadClass[
  numbers=noenddot,
  captions=tableheading,
  listof=totoc,
  bibliography=totoc,
  fontsize=10.5pt,
  toc=flat,
  DIV=calc
]{scrartcl}
\RequirePackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\KOMAoptions{
  headsepline,
  footsepline
}
\recalctypearea
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{myclass}
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{Header Text}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

---

Some remarks:

I have replaced the old command `\clearscrheadfoot` by `\clearpairofpagestyles`. Loading `scrlayer-scrpage` already activates pagestyle `scrheadings`. Note that this package also redefines `headings` and `plain` as aliases of `scrheadings` and `plain.scrheadings`.

Note that there is no DIV value predefined for `fontsize=10.5pt` and the default paper size a4. So you will get a warning that `DIV=1` is used. That means a good `DIV` value will be calculated. To avoid this warning I set `DIV=calc` explicitly.

In the first example I have used

```
\KOMAoptions{
  headinclude,
  footinclude
}
\recalctypearea
```

because the class options `headsepline` and `footsepline` sets the `typearea` options `headinclude` and `footinclude`. But if I use `headsepline` and `footsepline` as package options for `scrlayer-scrpage` I have to set the options `headinclude` and `footinclude` for `typearea` explicitly. The command `\recalctypearea` recalculates the page layout taking these options into account.

In the second example with

```
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\KOMAoptions{
  headsepline,
  footsepline
}
\recalctypearea
```

`headsepline` and `footsepline` are used for both the package `scrlayer-scrpage` and the KOMA-Script class. So `headinclude` and `footinclude` are set automatically. But I have to use `\recalctypearea` too to recalculate the page layout.

If you do not want to set the `typearea` options `headinclude` and `footinclude` use `headsepline` and `footsepline` only as package options for `scrlayer-scrpage`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Would you mind explaining the following lines briefly? 
`DIV=calc`
and
`\KOMAoptions{
  headinclude,
  footinclude
}
\recalctypearea`

Comment: See my updated answer.