# Getting LyX to honor paper size of LaTeX class?

Tags: koma-script, documentclass-writing

I'm not sure, if I'm just overlooking a simple preference setting or if what I would like to achieve is possible at all...

Anyway, I recently created a LaTeX class file (it's based on scrbook from the KOMA-Script package, but that might be beside the point) that looks like that:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{MyBook}[2016/06/03 My Book Class]

\LoadClass[
paper=17cm:22cm,
DIV=12,
twoside,
fontsize=9pt,
toc=flat
]{scrbook}

(...skipping a few more adjustments...)
```

I then created a LyX layout file by simply copying the contents of the original file `scrbook.layout`:

```
#% Do not delete the line below; configure depends on this
#  \DeclareLaTeXClass{MyBook}

Format 35
Input scrclass.inc
Input numreport.inc

Sides                   2
PageStyle               Headings

NoStyle Abstract


Style Chapter
    LabelString          "\thechapter"
    TocLevel 0
End


# Equations are numbered by chapter
Counter equation
    Within chapter
    LabelString "\thechapter.\arabic{equation}"
End


Style Bibliography
    TopSep                4
    LabelString           "Bibliography"
    LabelFont
      Series              Bold
      Size                Largest
    EndFont
End
```

I put the files into the correct directories, reconfigured LyX and so far, everything is working perfectly.

...well, except for the fact that LyX seems to ignore both the paper size (set as 17cm:22cm) and the margins (defined by setting DIV=12). Instead LyX always uses A4 for the paper size and standard margins (not sure how big). I'm assuming that LyX takes these from its own set of preferences, instead of honoring the class settings.

I could, of course, define the paper size and the margins in the preferences of the LyX document itself. However, I would like to give the class definition to several authors, without them having to do any further adjustments in the preferences. So, I would really prefer to define the paper size and the margins in a more central place.

Is this possible? Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wouldn't it be a good idea to share the layout file as well? Additionally, check if LyX uses package `geometry` by default. It will override stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Alright, will do that. (As far as I can see, `geometry` isn't used. Not sure, if I checked all possible places, though.)

Comment: This has nothing to do with LyX. Your LaTeX class does some dodgy stuff. Note also, that you get an error because you are not setting a proper date. [Unused global option in KOMAscript wrapper class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/242251)

Comment: As there is a very clear warning when not going to the LyX level, i vote to close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: I removed the specification of the date just for posting this here. Wasn't aware that it was important and would produce an error, if missing. Will add it back in. As to the possible duplicate: Will check that... Thanks for your help.

Comment: So, yes, that indeed solved my problem. Frankly, I couldn't get the first version using `\PassOptionsToPackage` to work, but the second one, using `\KOMAoptions` worked well. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: First one works as well, i tested it.

Comment: So, how can I tag your comments as useful? Or mark the question as duplicate?

Comment: I have never asked a question, so i am not sure. Maybe to the left of your username under the qustion is a close button? If not, others will also vote as duplicate.

Comment: There's a delete - button of course ;-)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.